# How to remove all images from a ppt files?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, presentation

I have a big (~250Mb) ppt file (created on windows i guess) with much text and some images (high definition).

I have to drop all images (i dont actually need to save them, just rip them out the presentation) from the ppt file: is there a way (via command line perhaps?) to automatically remove all of them?

Answer (score 3):

Using *office is not always an useful way to manipulate a PowerPoint file directly.

#### PROGRAMMATIC SOLUTIONS

I assume that you do not want a programmatic solution.  If you did, you might consider using *Apache Poi*, which provides Java libraries for manipulation of Microsoft Office files.

#### MANIPULATING AN IMPRESS BINARY

1. To use a *office, product, what you need to do is open the `*.ppt` (or `*.pptx`) in and save it as an ODF Presentation (`*.odp`).
2. Using a Zip utility, you can open **A COPY OF THE** `*.odp` and look for an images subdirectory.  (There may be more than one.)
3. You can delete them wholesale or selectively delete the ones that are obviously the high-resolution ones.
4. Close the modified Zip, rename back to *.odp if necessary, and re-open it in *office Impress.  You may receive warnings about the document being damaged.  Let the software attempt to recover the damage.  You should have something that doesn't have the images any longer.

#### USING SKYDRIVE ON-LINE POWERPOINT TO MODIFY THE DOCUMENT

If your problem is that *office Impress won't open the `*.ppt`/`*.pptx` in the first place, or the `*.odp` modification doesn't work, you will need to find a way to delete the images using Microsoft PowerPoint software.  One way is to get a Skydrive account (requires a Windows Live ID), upload the PPT file there, and edit it on-line using your browser. This is also a general way to view a `*.ppt`/`*.pptx` file when you don't have Microsoft Office software.  Not all features of PowerPoint are preserved in the SkyDrive editor; you should be able to make the changes you want.